# Are there any time-periodic solutions to Einstein's equations apart from black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, dissipation, time-reversal-symmetry

Are there any solutions to Einstein's equations which are periodic in time?

A black hole only has mass, charge and angular momentum according to the no-hair theorem. (Although this might just mean in the limit as time goes to infinity because when two black holes collide the shape of their combined horizon would be extra information).

Would a binary black hole system be periodic? I'm not sure because it might give off gravitational waves and collapse. (But there is also the time reverse of this where a single black hole absorbs gravitational waves and splits in two!)

What about a pair of black holes in a Universe that is expanding so fast that they always stay the same distance apart?

Comment: For me, the most interesting part of zooby’s question is the scenario he raises about a black hole absorbing gravitational radiation and splitting in two. It seems like this should be impossible, but it also seems like he’s right that it’s just the (absurdly improbable) time-reverse of black hole merger, and therefore possible in principle.

Comment: @G. Smith I'm not sure whether black holes emitting gravitational waves is purely GR or if there is some QM and thermodynamics thrown in there...

Comment: Two black holes orbiting each other definitely radiate gravitational waves to infinity. This is pure GR and needs no QM or thermodynamics. The loss of energy in the form of gravitatinal waves causes them to slowly inspiral and eventually merge. When they are sufficiently far apart, you can just compute the energy loss using the quadrupole formula for gravitational radiation. When they get close, you have to use numerical GR on a computer.

Comment: The question in the last sentence of your post is answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/363821/does-gravity-keep-nearby-galaxies-from-flying-apart-in-space-expansion

Comment: "*But there is also the time reverse of this where a single black hole absorbs gravitational waves and splits in two!*" - Is there a time reversal of a glass vase breaking into pieces?

Comment: @G. Smith Time reversal converts black holes into white holes

Comment: @safesphere Of course.

Comment: @zooby I need to go there, as I have broken a number of  vases :)

Comment: @safesphere You're already here. You just need to be lucky.

Comment: interesting question. Sadly I don't think that the question *how lucky you have to get to split a rotating black hole with incoming gravitational waves* can be quantified exactly with a classical theory like GR

Answer (score 3):

In the paper *[Non-Existence of Time-Periodic Vacuum Spacetimes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04592)* it is said that,

> This paper addresses the question whether there exist asymptotically flat solutions of the Einstein vacuum equations which are “periodic in time” in a suitable
>   sense. We show that any such solution must necessarily be stationary near infinity.
>   Thus, genuinely “time periodic” solutions do not exist, at least in a neighborhood
>   of (null) infinity.

Of course, in the general case, one can write down any time periodic metric, and compute the stress-energy tensor, thus offering a "solution" for that particular stress-energy, if physically sensible.

In the book, *Exact Solutions to Einstein's Field Equations*, there are plenty of solutions with a $\partial_t$ Killing vector which are thus technically periodic in time.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @JamalS answer, the quoted result of Alexakis & Schlue means that any time-periodic solution must be non-asymptotically flat or non-vacuum.

For example, it is easy to construct a [pp-wave solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime) which would be periodic with a suitable choice of time coordinate.

The resonant properties of anti-de Sitter spacetime also provide possibility to construct time-periodic non-black hole solutions, which are asymptotically AdS. Though no explicit metrics for such spacetimes are known presently, a paper

- Horowitz, G. T., & Santos, J. E. (2014). *Geons and the instability of Anti-de Sitter spacetime*, [arXiv:1408.5906](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5906).

provides us with a numerical construction of such solution, a *geon*, with a helical symmetry.

Comment: What about a spherically closed universe with black holes on both poles?